# Different access level for users and admin using php

Tags: php, mysql

What am I trying to do is setup different landing pages, after login, base on access level, I am talking about PHP and MySQL of course :)

I have a database with a users table, the users table have basically 3 fields:

`user,pass,access`

and I have 2 basics access level:

`(1=user, 5=admin)`

I found some examples online, even here, but for some reason I haven't been able to make it work. here what I got:

`login.php`

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="POST" action="login_engine.php">
<p>Please enter your login information:</p>
<label>User</label><input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" />
<label>Password</label><input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

and this is the engine:

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

// username and password sent from form
$MyUsername = $_POST['Username'];
$MyPassword = $_POST['Password'];


$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user=$MyUsername and pass=$MyPassword";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count===1){
  // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "home.php"
  session_register("user");
  session_register("pass");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    if($row['access']=='5')
    {
      header("home1.php");
    }
    else
    {
      header("home2.php");
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Invalid! Please try again PC.";
  echo "<br>";
  echo $_POST['Username'];
  echo "<br>";
  echo $MyUsername;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $_POST['Password'];
  echo "<br>";
  echo $MyPassword;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $sql;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $result;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $count;
}

//mysql_close();
?>
```

and this is the output:

```
Invalid! Please try again PC.
userdemo
userdemo
mypassword
mypassword
SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user=userdemo and pass=mypassword
```

First sign that something is wrong is that the variables $result and $count are not being printed on the error message (I had then showing some message but I changed the code so much that I lost track of what I did to make then stop showing info, but i remember that $result was showing something like "... #4" and $count was showing "0".)

I understand that something is wrong, because its going to the end of the PHP script: the last else, but the `$sql` seems right (i might be wrong here).

anyone have any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: **WARNING!** You have an [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability in your code! You are also using the `mysql_` family of functions, which will be *deprecated and removed from PHP* in future versions. You should take this opportunity to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) so you can leverage [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code should always return the number of row count as 0; this is because all string inputs in an sql statement.
Replace

```
 
  $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user=$MyUsername and pass=$MyPassword";
```

with

```
 
  $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user='$MyUsername' and pass='$MyPassword'";
```

This solves part of your immediate problem, unless either the **user** or **pass** inputs has an apostrophe in it, in which case, we are back to square one. 
Using

```
 
   $MyUsername = mysql_real_escape_string($MyUsername);
   $MyPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($MyPassword);
```

before my initial code should resolve that issue. 
 This answers your question and resolves your current issue.

### Much More Importantly

**First**, **mysql** has been [depreciated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php); stop using it for new projects, and convert existing projects to either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). 
 
**Second**, that code is very much insecure; your data can be wiped due to SQL Injection. Use the suggested methods in the first point to make it more secure. 
 
Hope this helps......at all.

Comment: Thanks Kneel. it really helped and I already implemented the scape strings, and will look onto mysqli. Thanks again :)

Comment: That's good; you need to select one of the answers as the **accepted answer** or it might reduce people's interest to help you later.

Answer (score 0):

#### Enclose the string within quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user=userdemo and pass=mypassword
```

#### Replace it with:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user='userdemo' and pass='mypassword'
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, if i put the quotes, the page come up empty:$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user='$MyUsername' and pass='$MyPassword'"; this doesn't work. curiously enough if i put single quotes in only one of the variables I still get the error message but if I put both the page comes up empty

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes should work fine but alternatively you can try:

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // username and password sent from form
    $MyUsername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
    $MyPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user='" . $MyUsername . "' AND pass='" . $MyPassword . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($count) {
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "home.php"
        session_register("user");
        session_register("pass");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($row['access'] == '5') {
                header("home1.php");
            } else {
                header("home2.php");
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid! Please try again PC.";
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_POST['Username'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $MyUsername;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $_POST['Password'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $MyPassword;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $sql;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $result;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $count;
    }
}
//mysql_close();
?>
```

You should also consider limiting your query to 1 result then getting rid of the while loop. I've also added `mysql_real_escape_string()` to your `$_POST` variables.

Comment: Hey Sean, thank you for you help. But unfortunately it didnt work, I end up with a blank page, at the url bar it sows the login_engine.php. It means that the script shutdown (I think). Thats why Im here I have no idea why the quotes are giving me such a hassle and what am I doing wrong here that I cant get this script to work :(

Comment: Everything seems to work fine. I updated my answer so try that code. I added `if (!empty($_POST))` so you can check if there's even a post happening. I also added `or die(mysql_error())` let me know if anything changes or you get any errors.